# how to pass csrf token in jquery datatable/makeEditable function

Tags: jquery, datatables, csrf

I need to pass my token anti-CSRF token in makeEditable .

```
.makeEditable({
    sUpdateURL: "com/change/company.do",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') 
    },
    "aoColumns": [
                null,
                null,
                {
                   cssclass: "required",
                   onblur: 'submit'
                },
                null,
                null
    ]   
});
```

tried this but that doesnt work..Please help me to find a solution..thanks in Advance

Comment: can any one please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute an ajax post with request header in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900545/how-do-i-execute-an-ajax-post-with-request-header-in-angular)

Comment: @PaulSweatte, it is not even remotely a duplicate. The question is about this old, deprecated plugin no longer maintained -> https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/